# How do I add additional Claims data to Bearer token in .NET 8 Identity endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using the .NET 8 out of the box identity api endpoints as such

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyAppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

...

app.MapIdentityApi<MyAppUser>();
```

In my custom class MyAppUser I have an additional property called `TenantId`. I would like to add that data to the Bearer token that gets returned on the login endpoint.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.

I can add my own implementation of `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<>`

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyAppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppClaimsFactory>() // <--- here
    .AddApiEndpoints();
```

```
public class AppClaimsFactory : IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyAppUser>
{
  public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(MyAppUser user)
  {

    var claims = new Claim[] {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ?? ""),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, "true"),
      new Claim("TenantId", user.TenantId ?? ""), // <--- Here
    };
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer");

    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

    return Task.FromResult(claimsPrincipal);

  }
}
```

I will accept another answer that better explains this with more detail, but this might help someone else for now doing something similar.